# How can I call a function that is defined outside of a class from inside a class

Tags: php, function

So I haven't really tried much, as I'm new to OOP, all I tried is to make a function for setting the progress bar for an action. When I call it from inside the class it says the function doesn't exist. How can I get around this? Thanks!

If I don't call the function in a class the progress bars works fine.

```php
function progresSet($parama, $paramb) {
code to set prgress;

}

class register {

    function a(dasdsadasd) {
    
        progressSet('50', 'red');

    }

}
```

**ERRORS**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function progressSet() in /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php:280 Stack trace: #0 /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php(382): registerCntlr->main() #1 {main} thrown in /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php on line 280
```

Comment: You should be able to call any global functions from inside a class. This should work.

Comment: `dasdsadasd` should be `$dasdsadasd`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. There's not enough information here to determine what's wrong in the real application.

Comment: i tried, but i got this error
```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function progressSet() in /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php:280 Stack trace: #0 /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php(382): registerCntlr->main() #1 {main} thrown in /home/xkhckrzf/xenonmc/controller/controllers/register/main.php on line 280
```

Comment: also, i have the vars and all tht correct, i just ruched it here and didnt type the code properly, but outsie of a class the function works fine

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: first, second or third? i added some moreinfo to my answer, i posted the error

Comment: thats all the info ik, im new to oop, not rlly sure what else i cna add

Comment: `function progresSet($parama, $paramb)` the function name differs from the called function `progressSet('50', 'red');`

Comment: It has nothing to do with OOP, it's just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some typos but sure you can, take a look:

```
<?php

function progressSet($parama, $paramb) {
    echo $parama . " - " . $paramb;
}

class register {
    function classFunction($param1, $param2) {
        progressSet($param1, $param2);
    }
}


$register = new register();
$register->classFunction('50', 'red')
?>
```